# StreamGeometry Drawing in the centre of a control?

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a control with `Height=100, Width=100`. I'm using `StreamGeometry` by overriding the `OnRender` method in the code-behind to draw a chart. Unfortunately at the moment my `StreamGeometryContext` is drawing in the top left corner of my control:

```
StreamGeometry sectorGeometry = new StreamGeometry();
sectorGeometry.FillRule = FillRule.Nonzero;

    using (StreamGeometryContext geometryContext = sectorGeometry.Open())
      {
        geometryContext.BeginFigure(innerScreenPointBefore, true, true);   
        geometryContext.LineTo(outerScreenPointBefore, true, false);
        etc. etc.
```

Is there a way for me to set the positioning of the `sectorGeometry` within the control? The control currently has no XAML except the `UserControl` definition.

Comment: It's drawing at the top left corner because there's the origin of its coordinate system. Add half of the control's width and height to all coordinates to draw centered. Or give the control an appropriate negative left and top margin.

Comment: Or in OnRender call [PushTransform](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.drawingcontext.pushtransform(v=vs.110).aspx) with an appropriate TranslateTransform to move all drawings to the desired position.